# How do I Sum a total based on Grouping

Tags: vba, excel

I've got data (which changes every time) in 2 columns - basically state and number. This is an example:

**Example Data**

```
State           Total
Connecticut     624
Georgia         818
Washington      10
Arkansas        60
New Jersey      118
Ohio            2,797
N. Carolina     336
Illinois        168
California      186
Utah            69
Texas           183
Minnesota       172
Kansas          945
Florida         113
Arizona         1,430
S. Dakota       293
Puerto Rico     184
```

Each state needs to be grouped. The groupings are as follows:

**Groupings**

```
**US Group 1**
California
District of Columbia
Florida
Hawaii
Illinois
Michigan
Nevada
New York
Pennsylvania
Texas

**US Group 3**
Iowa
Idaho
Kansas
Maine
Missouri
Montana
North Dakota
Nebraska
New Hampshire
South Dakota
Utah
Wyoming
```

Every other state belongs in US Group 2..

What I am trying to do is sum a total for each group. So in this example I would have totals of:

**Totals**

```
650 in Group 1 (4 states)
6365 in Group 2 (9 states)
1307 in Group 3 (3 states)
```

So what I would like to do each time I get a new spreadsheet with this data, is not have to create an if/countif/sumif formula each time. I figure it would be much more efficient to select my data and possibly run a macro which will do that (possibly checking against some legend or something)

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have been banging my head against the VBA editor for 2 days now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way.

Step 1:  Create a named range for each of your groups.

Step 2: Try this formula: `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A2:A18,Group1,B2:B18))`

### Formula Breakdown:

A2:A18 is the the state names

Group1 is the named range that has each of your states in group 1

B2:B18 is the values you want to sum.

It's important that your state names and the values you want summed are the same size (number of rows).  You should also standardize your state names.  Having S. Dakota in your data and South Dakota in your named range won't work.  Either add in the different variations of the state name(s) to your list, or standardize your data coming in.

To get a clear visual of what the formula is doing, use the Evaluate Formula button on the Formulas Tab, it will be much better than me trying to explain it.

### EDIT

Try this formula for summing up values that are not in Group1 or Group3:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A18,Group1,0)))),--(NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A18,Group3,0)))),B2:B18)
```

Seemed to work on my end.  Basically it works by only summing valyes in B2:B18 where both match functions return N/A (meaning it's not in the defined group list).

Comment: I just did that and it worked a peach! I also noticed the S Dakota while doing it thanks - I'll just have to scan the data once when it comes in to make sure it's standardized

So I suppose to make it an easy to use form for the future, I can just create a worksheet for only the names ranges and then whenever I get the state data, I can always copy/paste into columns A and B... you think?

Comment: Yep, you can update your named ranges as needed and your formula(s) will calculate correctly!

Comment: Sorry - but how do I add up for Group 2 - which is every state not in 1 and 2? I need to do like a Sumif Not...

Comment: I think the easiest thing is to add them all and then subtract the sum of group 1 and the sum of group 3.  I can post an example if you need me to.

Comment: No I can do that - that's just the difference between groups .. I just figured there was a way to do a negative

Answer (score 0):

Use a vlookup with a mapping of your states to groups.  Then from the group number, add it if it's found, or add 0.